# Page returns JSON when user clicks on back

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, laravel

Hello in my page controller i have it setup so that when the page loads it detects whether or not it was an ajax request, if it was then it sends back a json if not the it returns the view with the object data attached to it. eg:

```
if($request->ajax())
{
    $responseCode = 200;
    $responseMessage = 'Success';
    $responseData = [];

    return [
        'responseCode' => $responseCode,
        'responseMessage' => $responseMessage,
        'responseData' => $responseData
    ];
}
else {

    return view('tickets.payment.summary')->with(['cart' => array()]);

}
```

This works well however i noticed when that when i navigate to a different page then decided to go back to the previous page i was on by clicking the browser's back button when the page shows it displays the JSON instead not till i refresh the page again does the page itself show:

[image]

I would like to know what causes this and if there is a way i can stop this from happening.

Also i would like to point out that i use AngularJs on my frontend, this information might not matter but i did read something about how AngularJS returns a Json when the page loads instead of refreshing the whole page, let's just say i think that might be the culprit, not sure though.

Comment: Sorry but, why do you need to handle the same request returning a view or an json? It seems an unusual approach, normally you should let Angular to handle the view and just provider the returned data from your web services, it looks like you have a link or something and you use the same URL of the resource for `model` and `view`

Comment: Thats exactly what i am doing, the view loads then angular fetches the data via ajax or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Do you need to solve an AJAX before the view loads?

Comment: Nope not before, only after